# Package is not available in sample folder of android sdk

Tags: android

There is "action bar compatibilty" package in android 3.0 in android
developer site . i have installed android 3.0 but  i don't get "action
bar compatibilty" package in android -sdk.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find a particular response useful, please upvote it. If a response is the correct answer to your question. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be included in the compatibility package that you installed. If you go to {android_install_location}/extras/android/compatibility/v13/samples/Support13Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv13/app you can see and example of how to use the action bar.